# build log error on xamarin.forms android project

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, msbuild, xamarin.android

i get a build error using xamarin , the program used to run , i did a reinstall on my new laptop and now it doesnt work , tried doing a recode still same error, im thinking the program has something it depends on is there a way to see what it might be? heres the build log -

```
MainActivity.cs(16,30,16,45): warning CS0618: 'AndroidActivity' is obsolete: 'AndroidActivity is obsolete as of version 1.3, please use FormsApplicationActivity'

MainActivity.cs(24,4,24,30): warning CS0618: 'FormsApplicationActivity.SetPage(Page)' is obsolete: 'Please use protected LoadApplication (Application app) instead'

C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(379,5): mandroid error XA9005: User code size, 2961791 bytes, is larger than 131072 and requires aáIndieá(or higher) License.

C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(379,5): mandroid error XA9006: Using type `Android.Runtime.JNIEnv` requiresáIndieá(or higher) License.
2 Warning(s)

2 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:02.98
```

Comment: You need to buy a Xamarin Indie or higher license, as your app exceeds the Starter License limits. You can avail a Xamarin Business equivalent Student license too, if you are a student.

Comment: alright which is strange coz i do have a indie license ?

Comment: is there a place i need to sign in on xamarin besides the website which i already am ?

Comment: aah found it now !! man ! thanks ur a legend !!!

Answer (score 0):

**ERROR:**
MainActivity.cs(16,30,16,45): warning CS0618: 'AndroidActivity' is obsolete: 'AndroidActivity is obsolete as of version 1.3, please use FormsApplicationActivity'

Just change  public class MainActivity : AndroidActivity
to 
public class MainActivity : FormsApplicationActivity